# MySQL slave not using relay logs

Tags: mysql, replication, gtid

I have a slave using TokuDB tables, but replicating from a Master that us using InnoDB tables. The master is part of PXC, and the slave, with TokuDB tables, just uses regular percona server (not XtraDB).

When i run replication with multiple Applications connecting to the master, it seems like the slave server is not using relay_log and hence causing replication issues as show below:

```
2016-02-25 16:42:04 9604 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=db-kdb-slave-6-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2016-02-25 16:42:05 9604 [Warning] Recovery from master pos 552554502 and file mysqld-bin.001163. Previous relay log pos and relay log file had been set to 552554714, ./db-kdb-slave-6-relay-bin.002933 respectively.
2016-02-25 16:42:05 9604 [Warning] Storing MySQL user name or password information in the master info repository is not secure and is therefore not recommended. Please consider using the USER and PASSWORD connection options for START SLAVE; see the 'START SLAVE Syntax' in the MySQL Manual for more information.
```

More info: I have GTID enabled, and the slave also has log_bin enabled. Both servers are running on Ubuntu 14.04, and have the same hardware and server specs.

My question is, how can i make sure that the slave is using relay_log?

Comment: Have you checked if the master and slave are running the same version of mysql?

Comment: Yes they are. But i am also using GTID